# How to derive a formula of propositional calculus with basic rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

With only the operators $\land$ (and), $\lor$ (or), $\lnot$ (not), $\to$ (conditional) and their introduction and elimination rules, could someone help me to derive the basic fact

$p \to q$

therefore $ \lnot p \lor q$.

This is not a homework problem, but if I understood how to do this one, I'm pretty sure that I could figure out the more difficult ones.

Comment: I think I can guess at the introduction and elimination rules for $\land$, $\lor$ and $\rightarrow$.  But, the introduction and elimination rules for $\lnot$ vary quite a bit more.  So, could you state them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the set of rules of [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

1) $p \to q$ --- premise

2) $\lnot (\lnot p \lor q)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot p$ --- assumed [b]

4) $\lnot p \lor q$ --- from 3) by $\lor$-intro

5) $p$ --- from the contradiction with  2) and 4) and [Double Negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Double_negative_elimination), discharging [b]

6) $q$ --- from 1) and 5) by $\to$-elim

7) $\lnot p \lor q$ --- from 6) by $\lor$-intro

> 8) $\lnot p \lor q$ --- from the contradiction with 2) and 7) and Double Negation, discharging [a].

Comment: AndyPBJ didn't mention $\bot$.

Comment: Thanks, it's difficult to say exactly what rules I need since in an introductory course I only know one set, and the instructor didn't exactly say that it was Natural Deduction. This answered my question.